# I'm trying to create a game map using sprites, but I just used up all the RAM on my laptop

Tags: java, libgdx

Was pretty funny to be honest.

Basically I understand the problem, I'm currently trying to create a topdown game and I'm trying to generate the map. I've currently got a 2d array of "tiles" which I populate with 480 tile objects, each holding their own type (wall, floor, water) and color.

I then use this 2d array to create 480 sprites using Pixmaps (extremely memory intensive I know), and individually draw each of the sprites onto the map within the render() function.

Doing this multiple times a second obviously used up all the RAM on my laptop and crashed the entire system, which makes sense. The problem is that if I only set it to drawn the sprites once, they then get overwritten by the next call of render().

I need a way to be able to draw each of these individual tiles on screen to make up the game's map. But being new to LibGDX I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I've had way more sprites that that, you're doing something very wrong

Comment: Some of your relevant code may help. You're not creating (new) Pixmaps every render or something like that and not disposing them are you?

Comment: @PeterR That's exactly what I'm doing. I'll show you the function. The function call is within render() https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dbbe5b60fdc56e2642540c5889715230 As you can see the 2d array is being passed to the function, then the array is accessed and a pixelmap is created based on the colour of the tile accessed, then a texture and finally a sprite is created from the pixelmap. Then the tile sprite is being drawn.

Comment: I can't comment on the design of it, haven't done anything like that specifically. Seems like too many new() in a render for my liking, but that's just me. notice you're also doing a new Texture from the pixmap. Texture is also disposable, and you're not disposing that.That might be why you run out of memory. Also, the docs say that drawing pixmaps to a texture are not fast and should be used with care. If you're doing that inside your render that many times, performance might be affected too (if you find your memory issue)

Comment: What would you suggest instead for trying to create a tile based map? I'm well aware that this isn't the best solution to do this. I'd rather scrap this idea all together and try something better

Comment: I will leave for someone else to offer a suggestion, I haven't done much with tile based maps. I was just commenting that maybe you're not disposing everything you should (the textures) in your render and that could be causing your memory issues. No comment on the design.

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway!

Comment: why dont you use TextureRegions?

Answer (score 0):

Never create objects in render/update method method. Creation of `Texture` and `Pixmap` object is render method is...., what I say just don't do that.

If color is point, that why you're creating number of Texture use `Sprite` that having the geometry, color, and texture information for drawing 2D sprites.

```
Texture pmTexture;    

@Override
public void create() {

    Pixmap pm = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pm.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pm.fillRectangle(0,0,1,1);

    pmTexture = new Texture(pm);
    pm.dispose();
    allSprite=new Sprite[width][height];
    createTileSprites(...);
}

Sprite allSprite[][]; 

private void createTileSprites(Tile[][] tiles){

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

            allSprite[x][y] = new Sprite(pmTexture);
            allSprite[x][y].setSize(16,16);
            allSprite[x][y].setColor(tiles[x][y].getColor());
            allSprite[x][y].setPosition((x*16), (y*16));
        }      
    }

}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl...

    spriteBatch.begin();
       for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
           for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
               allSprite[x][y].draw(spriteBatch);
     spriteBatch.end();
}
```